# Maven archetype generate and open in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-archetype

I found an eclipse archetype under github (https://github.com/alapierre/altkom). I downloaded the zip file and try to generate a project from this archetype and run it in my eclipse. The point is I get "archetype not found" all the time? 
Could you help with a way to generate a project from this artifact?

What I`ve tried are some variatios of:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=pl.com.softproject.archetypes.springmvc -DarchetypeArtifactId=spring-mvc-spring-data-archetype -DarchetypeVersion=1.0-SNAPSHOT -DgroupId=com.test -DartifactId=myNewProject
```

Eventually I got also

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2
.2:generate (default-cli) on project spring-mvc-spring-data-archetype: org.apach
e.maven.archetype.exception.InvalidPackaging: Unable to add module to the curren
t project as it is not of packaging type 'pom'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, the problem was I tried to run mvn generate in the same directory as the archetype was and that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Before you can use the archetype, you need to install it somewhere where Maven can find it.

Run `mvn install` in the folder of the archetype which contains the `pom.xml` file. Afterwards, it should work.

Comment: Hi, I know I have to do mvn install (forgot to mention I have done it- sorry)... So the problem is something else

Comment: It seems you have several problems. Can you please narrow it down to a single problem per question? What specifically doesn't work and what's the error message and what do you expect to happen?